# Redirection with easyadmin is not good

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

When I go to domaine.com/admin I have the easyadmin page and it works well and I am identified correctly.

On the other hand, when I click in a tab of the menu, the redirection is not good: it directs me to localhost:9000/new-page instead of domain.com/new-page.
the localhost:9000 corresponds to my docker address on the vps.

> yield MenuItem::linkToCrud('Equipement', 'fas fa-list',
> Equipement::class);

EquipementCrudController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\DataTourisme\Equipement;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;

class EquipementCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Equipement::class;
    }

    /*
    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            IdField::new('id'),
            TextField::new('title'),
            TextEditorField::new('description'),
        ];
    }
    */
}
```

I have the problem only in production and not on the development server locally

Comment: Please share more details about your configuration. `domain.com/new-page` does not look like anything that EasyAdmin serves

Comment: I have the problem only in production and not on the development server locally